# Can the destination of my ssh tunnel be detected?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a machine called `mypc` connected to the network, and I want to communicate with another machine (outside of the network) called `dest` via an intermedia machine (also outside of the network) called `proxy`. I create a tunnel on `mypc` as:

`user@mypc$ ssh -L 9999:dest:3333 proxy`

Is the traffic I pass to `dest` via `proxy` visible on the network `mypc` is connected to? Can any sysadmin see the address/name of `dest`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume then you mean traffic which is created by connecting to `localhost` tcp port `9999` and your service on the `dest` runs on the port `3333`.

In this case, the answer is "NO", the network where `mypc` only sees ssh traffic to the `proxy`. They have no clue what is inside and can't possibly know if you are working with `proxy` itself or connect somewhere through it.

However, there are probability-based side channels, which can sometimes differentiate things. For example, HTTP has characteristic traffic patterns which are visible even when you tunnel it through SSH. However, nobody still may know that for sure and it is not visible where this traffic was really directed, so no, it is no way to know you're talking with `dest`.